# Custom Validation for Child Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

***HTML*** part

```html
<c-lookup-lwc
       unique-key="dealerid"
       data-name="Manufacturer__c"
       data-class="validateinput"
       obj-name="Manufacturer__c"
       icon-name="standard:custom"
       label-name="Manufacturer"
       display-fields="Name"
       display-format="Name"
       onvalueselect={handleValueChange}
       placeholder="Search Manufacturer"
       create-record="false"
       filters=""
       value-id={recAsset.Manufacturer__c}
     >
     </c-lookup-lwc>
```

***Javascript*** part

```js
    let lookupCmp = this.template.querySelector('c-lookup-lwc[data-class="validateinput"]').value.id;
    
        console.log("**lookupCmp**" + lookupCmp);
    
        lookupCmp.setCustomValidity("Manufacturer value is required");
        
        lookupCmp.reportValidity();
```

Currently, the custom validation is not firing.

I am getting a **undefined** value in lookupCmp.

Suggest me a way to make the validation fires in the Lookup Component.

Comment: Syntax to access the element is correct, you have a problem with getting the value. Does this work? `this.template.querySelector('c-lookup-lwc[data-class="validateinput"]').getAttribute("value-id")`

Comment: Have you defined the public functions `setCustomValidity` and `reportValidity` in your custom lookup component?

Comment: setCustomValidity() and reportValidity() are standard functions and i have not defined. Just used these functions in my validation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.value.id` from the selector, that would return the actual DOM element from the selector, with that you can call the appropriate validity method.

```
let lookupCmp = this.template.querySelector('c-lookup-lwc[data-class="validateinput"]');
lookupCmp.setCustomValidity("Manufacturer value is required");
lookupCmp.reportValidity();
```

If there are more than one elements, the selector would return an array. In that case you need to call the methods on each selector result.

Comment: Tried your code. Only thing is how can i define `setCustomValidity()` and `reportValidity()` in child component `c-lookup-lwc`?

Comment: @shyam not exactly sure on what you are trying, this is different problem than your question. The right way to implement the validation would be inside the lookup component, other less traditional option is to send a component event from the lookup component to this component where you call set this error message.

Comment: Got it Raul thanks.